# Using pandas and PyTables (3.1.1) at the same time, re-opening an already open file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I use pandas and pytables (3.1.1) at once. The problem is that I already opened an HDF5 file with pytables and when I try to create a new HDF5Store with pandas

```
hdf5store = HDFStore(...)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 281, in __init__
    self.open(mode=mode, warn=False)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 387, in open
    self._handle = h5_open(self._path, self._mode)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 154, in h5_open
    return tables.openFile(path, mode)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/_past.py", line 35, in oldfunc
    return obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7_with_system_site_packages/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 296, in open_file
    _FILE_OPEN_POLICY))
ValueError: The file '/tmp/temp_folder_for_pypet_tests/experiments/tests/HDF5/merge1.hdf5' is already opened.  Please close it before reopening.  HDF5 v.1.8.4-patch1, FILE_OPEN_POLICY = 'strict'
```

How can I tell pandas to not reopen the file but simply use the already given file handle?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `mode='r'` explicity to force an open in read-only mode. Default is to open in `mode='a'` (append mode).

Recent versions of PyTables have become much more strict in only allowing a file to be opened in write mode ONCE ONLY, even across multiple processes/threads. This is to avoid possible corruption of the file.

You can open the file multiple times in read-only mode, if you have a recent HDF5 library version (otherwise you will get a different Exception).

Comment: Yes I know, but I have to write pandas data to the hdf5 file (so I need it in mode 'w'). I don't want pandas to re-open the file but simply use the file handle I already have.